# How to define a function with Church numerals in lambda-terms?

Tags: function, lambda-calculus, computation-theory, church-encoding, computability

How can I express the following function by a lambda term?

f(n) = T if n != 0.
F if n = 0.

n stands for a Church numeral.

I know that 0 := λf.λx.x where λx.x is the identity function and all other natural numbers can be expressed by n := λf.λx.f (f ... (f x)) which contains f n times more than the 0-term. E.g. 3 := λf.λx.f (f (f x)).

But how can I derive a valid λ-term for the function above? I think I need a y too for getting the T/F. Therefore I can express the number n by λf.(λxy.fxy), right? But what about the F and T? Is the following a right λ-term for the function above? λf.(λxy.fxy(yFT)) where T=λxy.x and F=λxy.y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're *given* the term for `n`. It is a function that expects two arguments, an `f` and a `z`:

```lisp
isZero n = n ( ;; f, a function, expecting x
               ;;       or the result of (f (f ... (f x) ...))
               λx.
               ;; but we know what we want it to return, always: it is:
                  F    ;; false, for n is _not_ 0
             )
             ( ;; the initial x, in case n is ......... 0!
               ;; so we know what we want it to be, in case n is 0:
               T       ;; true, for n _is_ 0
             )
```

and thus

```cpp
isZero = λn.n(λx.F)T
```

If `n` was 0, `isZero n` will return `T`; and otherwise, `F`:

```py
{0}(λx.F)T = T
{1}(λx.F)T = (λx.F)T = F
{2}(λx.F)T = (λx.F)((λx.F)T) = F
{3}(λx.F)T = (λx.F)((λx.F)((λx.F)T)) = F
....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since I was looking for a function that returns F if n is 0, T otherwise, I just have to switch T and F in your Solution.

Comment: ah, great. so it was `notZero` then. :)